# dtype in pandas to_sql raises ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, csv

I am able to successfully write the CSV data to SQLite using pandas in python using this code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(path + '/issues.csv')
df.to_sql('issues', connection, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

However, I want to define one of the columns as an integer, and according to the documents when I try to use this code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(path + '/issues.csv')
df.to_sql('issues', connection, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={"severity_int": sqlalchemy.types.Integer()})
```

I get an error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1722, in to_sql
    raise ValueError(f"{col} ({my_type}) not a string")
ValueError: severity_int (INTEGER) not a string
```

I think I am doing it right but don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know where the error is

No problem. I looked at the source file for where your error is thrown, and the issue only arises when the dtype passed is not a string, as the error message says.

```
if dtype is not None:
  for col, my_type in dtype.items():
    if not isinstance(my_type, str): #Right here!
      raise ValueError(
        "{column} ({type!s}) not a string".format(
          column=col, type=my_type
        )
      )
```

I also looked at the docs and see they import the types instead of composing as you did. Try it their way first:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer

df.to_sql('integers', con=engine, index=False, dtype={"A": Integer()})
                                                          #^ Right here
```

Comment: I did this exact. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok hang on, let me see what `Integer` is returning. Can you do me a favor though and tell me what version of sqlalchemy you're using?

Comment: Also, can you give me the columns and dtypes of your df?

Comment: Try with the parameter `"interger"` instead of `Integer()`. In the same to_sql file, there's a function called `def _sqlalchemy_type(self, col):` which tries to infer the `col_type` from another library function. Maybe that'll force the mapping. In addition, make sure the dtypes are set for every column in your `df` as you want. Use `df["column"] = df["column"].astype(desired_type)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to convert all columns to string. try this:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, for each typing I had, I simply had to put them between `" "`

`df.to_sql('integers', con=engine, index=False, dtype={"A": "INTEGER"})`